# Invalid input syntax for integer when submitting form

Tags: php, sql, forms, postgresql

I'm trying to send data from a simple form to a PostgreSQL database, but my server log is showing the error `Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer` The parts of code in question are:

Form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
[removed]
Total Pages: <input type="number" name="totalPages" id="totalpages"><br><br>
<input type="submit"> </form>
```

Line in insert.php indicated in error message:

```
pg_query("INSERT INTO books(coverurl, title, author, genre, totalpg)
VALUES('".$_POST['coverURL']."','".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['author']."','".$_POST['genre']."','".$_POST['totalpages']."')");
```

Looking around online I have found solutions mentioning incorrect use of `'` and `"` symbols, but that has only caused other syntax errors.

EDIT: Did not mention that `totalpg` in my database is a smallint

**SOLUTION:
Thank you to JoDev for this, changed `'".$_POST['totalpages']."'` to `".intval($_POST['totalPages'])."` and now it works perfectly.**

Comment: If you would consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead, not only would you get rid of this and many other similar problems, but you won't have the huge security issue you have with your app right now.

Comment: Or using [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php)

Comment: Do you get the error for any value entered ?

Comment: Do an `echo $_POST['totalpages']`. Is it a number? Is it empty?

Comment: ... better yet, `echo` the entire query and see where the problem is.

Comment: @rid I'll have a look through that page, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe cast the POST value to be sure, and remove the quote :

```
pg_query("INSERT INTO books(coverurl, title, author, genre, totalpg)
VALUES('".$_POST['coverURL']."','".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['author']."','".$_POST['genre']."',".intval($_POST['totalPages']).")");
```

**[EDIT]**
You make a mistake between HTML form and PHP. The correct case for youre value is : `$_POST['totalPages']` the **P** is in maj for the **`name`** attribute.

Your form is :

```
Total Pages: <input type="number" name="totalPages" id="totalpages">
```

The name is well **totalPages**...

Comment: Your suggestion has stopped the error, but it's only passing 0 into the database for totalpages (everything else is fine). any idea what might cause that?

Comment: Ok, so that's mean that `$_POST['totalpages']` is empty, or a string.... You have an error somewhere else. Do you fill the `input` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to add text in a numeric field.

Have you tried this:

```
pg_query("INSERT INTO books(coverurl, title, author, genre, totalpg)
VALUES('".$_POST['coverURL']."','".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['author']."','".$_POST['genre']."',".$_POST['totalpages'].")");
```

Comment: `'...'` is valid SQL for integers.

Comment: Nope, I mean `".$_POST['totalpages']."` instead of `'".$_POST['totalpages']."'`

Comment: That's what I mean too. `INSERT INTO table (intfield) VALUES ('1');` is valid SQL.

Comment: @ophintor Yes I tried that, I got a different syntax error instead.

Comment: @user2067499, you could also try `echo`-ing the failing query to see exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is an integer, consider using an int cast `(int)` before appending the value to the query. Do however note that all other variables [must be escaped](http://php.net/pg_escape_string) before appending them to the query, because one of them might contain a string that invalidates the query.

For example, if `$_POST['title']` would contain the value: `Why Hackers Don't Want You To Escape Strings`, then the query would become:

```
INSERT INTO books(coverurl, title, author, genre, totalpg)
VALUES('http://example.com/','Why Hackers Don't Want You To Escape Strings','J. Doe','Educational','400');
```

... which is invalid SQL.